# MIPS Processor I/O device support

Tags: cpu-architecture

In a MIPS processor, I/O address space 0xffff0000 to 0xffffffff is reserved for memory-mapped I/O. Assuming that an I/O device needs 3, 1, and 4 32-bit words for control, status and data registers respecitvely. How many I/O devices can be supported?

The correct answer is 2048, but I got 8192.

My thought process:
Subtract the two spaces to retrieve the amount of memory needed
ffffffff - ffff0000 = 0000ffff = 65535 bits = 2^16 - 1
Then divide by 32-bits and multiply by 8, but that is obviously wrong.

Can someone guide me through the steps to get the correct answer? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each devices uses: `(3+1+4) * 32 bits = 8 * 4 bytes = 32 bytes`

The available memory area is in bytes, not bits : 2^16 = `65536 bytes`

Thus, you have: `65536 bytes / 32 bytes = 2048`.

So **2048** devices are supported.